# [Vue warn]: Write operation failed: computed property is readonly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue3

Есть переменная объект `employees`, которая передается из `state` vuex.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState ({
        employee: state => state.day.employees,
    }),
},
```

При попытке изменить этот объект

```
this.employee = this.employee.map(x => {
    if(x.id === itemId) {
        x.cell_id = cell_id
    }
    return x
})
```

Вылезает ошибка `[Vue warn]: Write operation failed: computed property "employee" is readonly.` Как сделать чтобы этот объект можно было изменять?

Comment: Используйте [мутацию](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему
в `store`

```
mutations: {
    setEmployeesCell(state, data) {
        state.employees = state.employees.map(x => {
            if(x.id === data.item_id) {
                x.cell_id = data.cell_id
            }
            return x
        })
    }
},

actions: {
    setCell({ commit }, data) {
        commit('setEmployeesCell', data)
    }
}
```

на самой странице

```
methods: {
    onDrop() {
        data  = {
            item_id: itemId,
            cell_id: cell_id
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('day/setCell', data)
    }
}
```